# Python automatic variable assignment based on list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have a number of variables that I would like to create in an automated way based on 2 lists, but unsure how to do so. The objective is unique, but would help me immensely.

list 1 is a list of names -

```
subqueries = ['name', 'name2', 'name3']
```

list 2 is generated from a for loop -

```
def sub_view(qry,subqueries):
   qry_list = []
   for sub in subqueries:
       qry_list.append(qry + """ SELECT * FROM """ +sub+ """ WHERE id='book'""")
   return qry_list

qry_list = sub_view(qry,subqueries)
```

To get -

```
subqueries[0] = qry_list[0]
subqueries[1] = qry_list[1]
```

and so on many times.

Comment: "I have a number of variables that I would like to create in an automated way" -- why? That is what dictionaries are for. Just use a single variable.

Comment: Please use proper indentation in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip both files and create a dictionary

```
combined_query= dict(zip(subqueries, qry_list))
```

Comment: ok cool, and forgive my 'newness' but then does the name dictionary values become something i can extract as a variable? - so if i wanted to extract out the string value for 'name'?

Comment: combined_query['name'] should give you the corresponding query